# merging two timetables with some omitted data

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series

I have two dataframes:

df_old:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   b1  c   d1  e1
2   b2  c   d2  e2
3   b3  c   d3  e3
```

df:

```
A   B   C    D   F  
2   b2  c2   d0  f2
4   b4  c1   d4  f4
5   b5  c2   d5  f5
```

What i want them to merge into:

```
A   B   C    D   E   F  
1   b1  c   d1  e1   
2   b2  c2  d2  e2   f2
3   b3  c   d3  e3   
4   b4  c1  d4       f4
5   b5  c2  d5       f5
```

I use this code, but there is a problem when it comes to omitted rows, like in df['A'] rows 1 and 3:

```
df1 = df_old.loc[:,df_old.columns != 'C']
df2 = df.loc[:len(df_old)-1, df.columns != 'B']
df2 = df2.loc[:, df2.columns != 'D']
df_m = pandas.merge(df1, df2,
                            how='outer', on=['A'])
df_m = pandas.merge(df_m, df.loc[len(df_old)-1:, ],
                            how='outer', on=['A', 'B', 'D', 'F'])
```

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CHeck with `combine_first`

```
df_old.set_index('A',inplace=True)
df1.set_index('A',inplace=True)
yourdf=df_old.combine_first(df1)
yourdf.reset_index(inplace=True)

yourdf.update(df1[['C']])
yourdf
Out[80]: 
    B   C   D    E    F
A                      
1  b1   c  d1   e1  NaN
2  b2  c2  d2   e2   f2
3  b3   c  d3   e3  NaN
4  b4  c1  d4  NaN   f4
5  b5  c2  d5  NaN   f5
```

Comment: Thanx, but there is only one problem with second row, there has to be not d0, but d2. Is there some other way then saving df_old['D'] and attributing it to yourdf.loc[:len(df_old), 'D'] ?

Comment: @MaximZhevakin updated , change to `df_old.combine_first(df1)`

Comment: However, now there is c, but has to be c2. I have to do these changes manually, right? Because column c has to change but values in D have to stay as in df_old

Comment: @MaximZhevakin this make me confused , So you want C change and D not change

Comment: D values have to stay the same as in dataframe df_old, but values in C have to be updated from df (second dataframe). As i wrote in dataframe i want it to be merged into

Answer (score 1):

### `append`, `groupby`/`agg`, and `last`/`first`.

In some columns you want to keep the one from the first dataframe.  In other columns you prefer the value in the second dataframe.  If you use `agg` you can control which columns do which.  Make sure to `append` in the appropriate order that makes sense with the `last`/`first` you choose.

```
d = {'B': 'last', 'C': 'last', 'D': 'first', 'E': 'last', 'F': 'first'}
df_old.append(df).groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(d)

   A   B   C   D    E    F
0  1  b1   c  d1   e1  NaN
1  2  b2  c2  d2   e2   f2
2  3  b3   c  d3   e3  NaN
3  4  b4  c1  d4  NaN   f4
4  5  b5  c2  d5  NaN   f5
```